# Can we nuke the "grains"and "process" tags?

Tags: discussion

"Grains" seems useless, since we already have "Grain", and "Process" seems much too general to provide sane result-sets for tag searches. Instead, I think we should rely on more specific tags that refer to *parts* of the process, like "Boil", "Secondary" etc.

The same could also be said for the "Techniques" tag, but there might be merit in keeping it since, IMO, it has slightly more nuanced connotations than "Process".

Answer (score 3):

Merging grains into grain seems right.

Comment: I've merged grains into grain.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding process and techniques tags -
This is just a general observation and there are exceptions to this - the process tag seems to be used often together with more specific tags, when the question is about how to do something during the brewday or ferment, while techniques is used for small-scale process improvements, often to solve a specific problem.